# SPFX 1.7.1 - Full page apps - How to configure

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

So i've been away from SPFX for a while since they were still using the older version of React and i've got a question.

I can see that they added a developer preview of "Full Page apps". How can you use that? I installed my SPFX webpart using `--plusbeta`, but i can't find any answer on how to set that up.

Any tips ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, you need to programmatically set the PageLayoutType of the page to support full page apps. In the future, you will be able to configure this in your web part itself.

See this link on how to change the page layout:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages

```
o365 spo login https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing
o365 spo listitem set --webUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing --listTitle 'Site Pages' --id 3 --PageLayoutType SingleWebPartAppPage
```

Comment: Oh wait so there's no way to set this up without tenant admin? I only have site collection admin & an Apps for Sharepoint catalogue in which i upload my apps/webparts.

Comment: You should be able to set this without being a tenant admin as well. Try with the Office 365 CLI as shown in the link.

Comment: Nope, the CLI does not work without tenant admin. Anyway, i found a JS snippet in your link that seems to have done the trick, however, after creating the page & setting it to fullpage layout, how can i add the webpart to it since there's no EDIT button anymore (shows the empty page with the top menu and nothing else which i assume is the way it should work), or should the webpart be added before switching it to full page ?

EDIT: Reading that link better looks like i'm right, should add the webpart and then switch the page, thats kinda dumb, anyway, it should work fine, thanks !